# Looking for a decent library for credit card form validation on Angular 2+

Tags: angular, validation, credit-card

I have been searching and trying several libraries for credit card form validation. But none of them works well as my expectation.

First, I tried this library: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-credit-cards

But it is lack of maintenance and still exists unsolvable issue on its github repo, therefore, I can't use it at all.

Then I tried this library: 
https://github.com/nogorilla/angular-cc-library

It works quite well, it validates almosts common credit cards, but Visa card which I need the most. I cloned the library then tried with 3 different actual Visa cards, but none of them is validated.

So far those are all compatible library for Angular 2+ I could find, anyone has other suggestions please?

EDIT:
Angular-cc-library is now fixed to validate Visa card by their contributors.

Comment: You can use angular validation with a standard regex expression. https://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html

Comment: Thank you, I will give a try

Comment: @HoàngNguyễn What did you end up doing?   I am looking for a CC validator myself.